# how to get total number of people who view to an image?

Tags: node.js

I am making a page where there are some images with their name and total views of that image.

I made a logic like when someone clicked on the image, then the number of views increases by 1. But there is a problem like when any user clicked on that image multiple times, then the number of views increases by the number of times.

I just want that increments on the number of views by any user be only 1.

Can someone suggest to some proper way to do this?

Comment: What do you use for the backend service to increment the counter? Express?

Comment: Use an `if` statement with a condition which tells if the user has already viewed the image.

Comment: Maybe instead of adding one just use a boolean flag? Start it as false, and when clicked turn it to true. Then, if the flag is true send an update to your database.

Comment: @JonasSchwabe Yes, I am using express.

Comment: If you are hosting the image, you should create middleware that increases the views by 1 each time the image route is requested. Regulate the counter with sessions so that users can't just keep refreshing the page.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: @Rupesh if you figure that out, sell your service to youtube, twitch, imgur, and every other website that currently estimates view counts by using a combination of fingerprinting and IP addresses.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Yes, I think I want the same.

Comment: @MaxBaldwin, But there will be the problem in case of any guest user.

Comment: @Rupesh tag registered users with a specific key on their session cookie. If they don't have that specific key on your session cookie, don't increment.

Answer (score 1):

You need to identify the user in your backend service usually using sessions.

The browser will store a cookie identifying a session or storing some information authenticated by your application.

When using sessions you can store the clicked images for a certain session, the user will be able to increment the counter again if he removes the session cookie.

For express you might use https://github.com/expressjs/session/

Comment: But there will be the problem in case of any guest user.

Comment: Sessions do not need to be authenticated. A guest might have a session as well and can therefor be identified as the same guest who already clicked on the image. As I said, when the user removes the session cookie he will be a new guest and able to increment the counter again. There is no real way to prevent this without authentication as far as I'm concerned